# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. RxAndroid

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I tried using RxAndroid

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> restApiFactory.testService().getListTest(7)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Test>>() {
```

but I got the following error :

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I have not Used `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

Comment: `UI`  should be updated from main thread , there is no escape from that

Comment: I know. but I do not know how to tell the observer main thread

Comment: add this `..observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before `.subscribe(new Observer<List<Te...`

Comment: I wrot in my question - I have not AndroidSchedulers class

Comment: and i also said , there is no escape and what do you mean by you don't have `AndroidSchedulers class`? you need to be specific regarding the issue and constraints

Comment: I have Schedulers.io()  .newThread() .computation() .. but in which library place AndroidSchedulers?

Comment: do you have  `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'` dependency

Comment: I have 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

Comment: to achieve this you need to add above mentioned library because the current one you are using is only for REST calls

Comment: try clean project or rebuild project

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to manipulate `UI` from main thread so in order to do that you need to tell rxandroid to notify changes on main thread so use

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> restApiFactory.testService().getListTest(7)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                //              ^^^^^^^^^^
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Test>>() {
```

and to obtain this, **you need to have a dependency as**

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

and your current dependencies are used to make retrofit retuns `rxAndroid` type response.

Comment: Can't we do without adding `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' ` this dependency. Can't we use `Schedulers`? I tried to use `Schedulers.trampoline() & Schedulers.newThread()` but giving me same error. Any idea?@Pavneet_Singh

Comment: @MaulikDodia I think it should work, hopefully you are not using any UI related work

Comment: It wasn't working, that's what I'm saying@Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 1):

You should be using
`observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` not `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

**Use as:-**

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```